# TIN creation process generating error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, error, 3d-analyst, tin

I'm having trouble generating a TIN. Repeatedly, I obtain:

> ERROR 050035: no features were added to the TIN.

I can't figure out what I'm doing incorrectly. There is only one feature, namely "DEM_points". Those points all have an Object_ID, a point shape, and an elevation number (a short) associated with them. There are 2864 of such points contained within the feature class.

Here are some screenshots of what I tried:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to contain details about the numbers of features, spatial references and dimensionality of your sources.

Comment: @Vince Is this better? Anything I should add? I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "spatial references" and the "dimensionality" of the sources.

Comment: Couple things to try: 
Make sure you input and output folders are in locations that dont start with \\ or _,
Name your output name something simple like 'TIN', Give ArcMap a restart

Comment: From your snips,this should work. Could you share your data maybe, this way I can try on my machine, see if I get the same error.

Comment: Points sit outside environment extent?

Comment: 050034: Check the source feature classes and make sure they aren't empty. If the spatial references for the features and the TIN are different, they should at least overlap in extent. Additionally, at least some data being added to the TIN, now or previously, must have z-values. They can't all be 2D.  In addition - as was suggested - copy input data to local drive